# Upgrading Hibernate 4 to 5 when using ddl-auto UPDATE

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, ddl

Hibernate 4 application setup

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultComponentSafeNamingStrategy
```

Hibernate 5 application setup

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy = org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyComponentPathImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy = org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

Tables and columns are generated respecting the old model **but foreing key names changes**.

So I have:

```
org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
Unable to execute schema management to JDBC target [alter table acidentepessoal_cruz_em add constraint FKddk6qn84r6c1kyhukvffaleao foreign key (emCruzamentos_id) references CruzamentoEm]
ORA-02275: such a referential constraint already exists in the table
```

When **ddl-auto** is `update` the framework try to create another FK because hibernate 5 generates a different FK name from previous version.

I tried to extends `ImplicitNamingStrategyComponentPathImpl` and delegate the FK name generation to `DefaultComponentSafeNamingStrategy`. I was surprised when I realized that this only handles table and column names.

**How to manage that? How to use hibernate 4 foreign key name generation in Hibernate 5? How to upgrade from Hibernate 4 to 5 when using ddl-auto = update?**

Comment: I have the same problem, it seems that hibernate 5 does not recognize the foreign keys already present in th db. Even if I remove them, it also tries to re-create already existing tables. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Appears to be an open Hibernate bug: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12195, sadly I have yet to find a way around it.